# Error in set access rights to folder in network programming

Tags: c#, network-programming

In my program first admin user must choose a folder that it should be in a shared folder and then my program should change its access rule to 'Deny' and every time that admin wants,the access rule of this folder should change to 'Allow' and then change to 'Deny' again.I do this with 'DirectorySecurity' class and its work correctly.but the problem occurres when another user wants to change the rule of this folder.at this times i recieve an error that tells me this user can not do this action.
please help me.

Comment: Hello, could you post the exception?

Comment: Are you asking why a user gets "Access Denied" errors when they've been denied access?

Comment: Seems like an ownership issue, the admin is able to perform I/O because he is owner of the folder, while other users are not. Also check the access permissions on the folder at time of error.

Comment: I think must check  Auditing and Owner that file!

Comment: Mr. Maddah: I recieve this error "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation".thanx for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
It's possible that user(which got error) not be **`Member of Administrator Group`** for that computer. as default administrators group is owner all file and directory.
Also you must check **`Owner and Auditing`** for that File Directory.
only user can access to special setting (like security) was define in owner security.